# Subset HTML String in R to remove date

Tags: string, r, date, subset

I'm trying to extract the date out of a character line in a .txt files that I've scraped from online; the date always comes on the same line and followed by the same HTML, however the date itself changes with each text. The below demonstrate two examples of the code from two .txt files.

```
"17"        <div align=\\center\\><br /><font face=\\Times New Roman\\ size=\\3\\><b>Tuesday, 3 February 2009</b></font>
"17"    "<div align=\"center\"><br /><font face=\"Times New Roman\" size=\"3\"><b>Tuesday, 10 February 2009</b></font>"
```

xpathSApply() doesn't work since I'm importing them into R as a .txt file that is read as a character; any thoughts on how to best extract that? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kinda silly, but works, if the tags `<b>` and `</b>` only appear once in your data.

If that is not the case, you can try changing the subscripts below:

```
x <- "<div align=\\center\\><br /><font face=\\Times New Roman\\ size=\\3\\><b>Tuesday, 3 February 2009</b></font>"

strsplit(strsplit(x, "<b>")[[1]][2], "</b>")[[1]][1]
```

A vectorized form is as follows:

```
sapply(strsplit(sapply(strsplit(x, "<b>"), function(y) y[2]), "</b>"), function(y) y[1])
```

If x is a vector of type character.

Comment: Thanks, this is fantastic. I'm a bit unfamiliar with the code, but is there a way to bring in the full line with the quotes without it erring; the line begins with "\"17\"\t\"<div align, however it errs when I include the quotes - is there something that needs to be altered here?

Comment: It worked for me with `x <- "\"17\"\t\"<div align=\"center\"><br /><font face=\"Times New Roman\" size=\"3\"><b>Tuesday, 10 February 2009</b></font>" > strsplit(strsplit(x, "<b>")[[1]][2], "</b>")[[1]][1]` gives `[1] "Tuesday, 10 February 2009"`

Comment: It works as well - and should be sufficient; I was hoping to make the code a bit more specific so that when it is looking at a long text document with lines that have the beginning and ending, "<b>" and "</b>", it is still able to identify the date via the more specific layout starting at "\"17\"\t\"<div ali..